# The dropdown value doesn't show selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I have to populate the values to drop down box from SQL. Classic ASP is the language I need to use. I was able to populate it; however, I am not being able to keep the selected value in the drop down. I kept the value "selected"  after "option value" inside the loop but the issue after doing this was: all the prior options keep on loading (selecting) in drop down until the one I selected comes in the list. Can anyone suggest/comment where/what am I missing?

```
    Categories:<select name="menu" onChange="if(options[selectedIndex].value != 0){location='test.asp?list=bybrand&brandID=' + options[selectedIndex].value + '', exit=false;}">
    <OPTION value=0 selected>-- SELECT --</OPTION>
    <% dim rs
        SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(brand) as brand FROM tblprdt"
        SET rs=objConn.Execute(SQL)  

        IF NOT (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) THEN 
            WHILE NOT rs.EOF
                Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & """ selected >" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
                rs.MoveNext
            WEND 
        ELSE
            Response.Write "<option >No categories available</option>"
        END IF
        rs.close
        SET rs = nothing
        %>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why are you using "selected" for each option that is generated?

Comment: @David Leverett: I apologized, I forgot to delete that selected. I kept there just to check if it works. If I remove it, the only option it would show is "--SELECT--"  but I want to show the value that I had recently selected.

Comment: Perhaps you could also post the generated code. 
I have a feeling the onChange event is the issue.

Comment: I just have to display a table which will be generated once the drop down value is selected. So I used that onChange event. Hence, there a simple select statement then a table. Does that make sense? @David Leverett

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value BrandId corresponds to a key field in your table tblprdt and that field is also called BrandId, change your query to

```
SQL = "SELECT BrandId, brand FROM tblprdt"
```

then later

```
      WHILE NOT rs.EOF
        if cint(rs("BrandId")) = cint(Request.Querystring("BrandId")) then
            Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("BrandId")," & ","@") & """ selected >" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
        else
            Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("BrandId")," & ","@") & ">" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
        end if
            rs.MoveNext
        WEND
```

EDIT I've just tested the js in your example and it just passes the value of `rs("brand")`, so it's much simpler.  Leave your query as it is and use

```
  WHILE NOT rs.EOF
    if replace(rs("BrandId")," & ","@") = Request.Querystring("BrandId") then
        Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("Brand")," & ","@") & """ selected >" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
    else
        Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(rs("brand")," & ","@") & ">" & rs("brand") & "</option>"
    end if
        rs.MoveNext
    WEND
```

Comment: Actually product id is the primary key for tblprdt. I called a query for brandID down before displaying table.i.e  "IF Request.QueryString("list") = "bybrand" THEN   do sql and display table ". I tried keeping both productid and brandID in my code as you mentioned above. The result was no options at all.